# how can I make all the input file copy in temporary directory that icreated

Tags: c#, html

how can I make all the input file available in temporary directory that I created. Only the last file are exist.. I want all the file from start to end of my file.
Hope somebody can find my problem here.

Below is my coding.

```
var partText = Global.PartText;
            Global.PartText = string.Empty;
            Global.TmpFileCount = 0;
            var tempfile = Global.TempContent;
            Global.TempContent = string.Empty;
            var temp = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Temp");
            if (Directory.Exists(temp))
            {
                Directory.Delete(temp, true);
            }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
            var content = File.ReadAllText(inputfile);
            tempfile = Path.Combine(temp, string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputfile), ".html"));
            File.WriteAllText(tempfile, content);
            var text = File.ReadAllText(tempfile);
            text = text.Replace("&", "&amp;");
            File.WriteAllText(tempfile, text);
            Global.TmpFileCount++;
            if (tempfile.Contains("<h1"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h1").Value;
            }
            else if (tempfile.Contains("<h2"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h2").Value;
            }
            else if (tempfile.Contains("<h3"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Value;
            }
            else if (tempfile.Contains("<h4"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h4").Value;
            }
            //Directory.Delete(temp, true);
            //var source = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
            //if (source.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).Any())
            //{
            //  var introduced5 = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
            //  if (introduced5.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First().Attributes("id").Any())
            //  {
            //      var introduced6 = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
            //      _chapterName = introduced6.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First().Attributes("id").First().Value;
            //  }
            //}
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "cover", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "cover";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "bibliography", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "bibliography";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "foreword", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "foreword";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "toc", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "toc";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "cop(yright)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "copyright-page";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "halftitlepage", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "title-page";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "titlepage", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "title-page";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "ded(ication)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return "dedication";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(ipName, "part", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Global.PartText = _chapterName;
                return "text";
            }
            Global.PartText = partText;
            const string str = "text";
            Global.FileCount++;
```

Comment: you should really start using the tools that are available in front of you meaning the `Debugger` ..don't just `Code and GO`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to combine all the html files in a directory into one, but you should really look at your code and understand what it is doing. Also when posting code and you are unsure about what you are doing, it helps a lot if you add comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the directory every time.  Change this:

```
        if (Directory.Exists(temp))
        {
            Directory.Delete(temp, true);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
```

To this:

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(temp))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
        }
```